# Calling a rest endpoint from AWS kinesis stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-kinesis

How do I hit a rest endpoint from a kinesis stream and fetch some data?

Is it even possible to hit a rest endpoint from Kinesis?

Comment: A kinesis stream is an AWS data transmission protocol - to extend it you need to create a Kinesis stream reader in code and then you can write the code to go out and fetch some other data too.

Answer (score 0):

No. Kinesis streams are simply a mechanism to store messages for a fixed time period, so that one or more consumers can read them.

If you want to do something the the messages on the stream, you need to write a consumer. Either an application that explicitly polls the stream, or a [Lambda that is triggered by the stream](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html).

Comment: Thanks! Just what I wanted to hear :)